# [UIProgressView setProgress:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b34190'

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I get the following error no matter where instantiate a progress bar when it calls set progress:

> [UIProgressView setProgress:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x5b34190'
>
> [progressView setProgress:0.5 animated:YES]; //exception is raise here

I just don't understand why, here is the code:

```
UIProgressView *pv = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    [pv setProgress:0.5 animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:pv];
```

Comment: Have you check for overrreleased objects? Sometimes this occurs when overreleased objects corrupt memory. If your app is multithreaded, check if all objects are accessed thread-safe and UI operations only in the main thread. This can as well corrupt memory and lead to these errors.

Comment: how are you keeping hold of the pointer to the ProgView? is it an ivar. Show us the connection between instantiation and setProgress

Comment: I am not using multithreading anywhere in the app

Comment: The code above is all the code, I got so frustrated I just added those 3 lines of code to a view and it still crashes with same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code, "as is" should work perfectly. The only condition that could prevent it from working is noted in the docs:

> #### `setProgress:animated:`
>
> Adjusts the current progress shown by the receiver, optionally
>   animating the change.
>
> `- (void)setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> …
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later. **`<--- note that`**
>
> **Declared In**
>
> UIProgressView.h`

Are you sure you're with iOS 5?

Comment: Thats the problem. This is not available before iOS 5. There was only the property for `progress` (`setProgress:`).

Comment: It's strange that it compiles though as my target is 4.3

Comment: @TheLearner `[obj shakespeare]` would compile too. This comes from Objective-C nature, message checking are deferred to runtime. That's dynamic binding, actually the methods are not called, only messages are sent.